# Why is my PSD rendering weird type characters when cropping canvas?

Tags: adobe, photoshop

First time posting a photoshop question. I hope you can help.

When I receive PSD files from our designers, I get weird behaviour.

**When I crop the canvas, all the type layers freak out and render weird characters.** 
My current solution is to rasterise the layer and then crop. This isn't ideal because I need to update text so I'm either undoing a lot or duplicating.

If I create a PSD with text layers and write out text, cropping isn't an issue. It only occurs when I am taking PSDs from others.

Below is the before / after (top/bottom):
[image]

Photoshop version: **Photoshop CC 2015.1.2 release.**

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks
Moe

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that you can rasterize the whole design to a  single layer so that if you want to crop the image just duplicate that layer and crop the section you want. This is not a good approach if your design is a vector graphic file or .ai design.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is currently what I am doing but it isn't ideal because I need to update text for dozens of layers so I'm rasterizing, cropping, undoing, updating text and then repeating for all the instances of text I need to crop.
I've updated the question to include my current method.